# Angular2. Http. Can't send post with body and set Content-Type

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm writing an app with using Angular2 as a front-end part(~2.4.0) and ASP.NET CORE as a back-end part.

I have a really huge problem with sending a post request. Chrome tells me that i have no body in request and also I can't set up content-type of request.

I tried in a few ways. But no one worked

```
         let headers = new Headers();
         headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         headers.append('authentication', `3123123123`);

         let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
         this.http
         .post('http://localhost:5000/api/user/login', JSON.stringify(this.loginModel), options)
         .subscribe((result) => {
                     if (result) {
                         .......
                     }
                 });
```

Second:

```
PostRequest(url:string,data:any) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');

    var requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        url: url,
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })

    return this.http.request(new Request(requestoptions))
        .map((res: Response) =>
        res.json()
    ).subscribe((result) => {
            if (result) {
                ....
            }
        });
}
```

Third one:

```
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');


    let body = JSON.stringify(loginDto);
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.http
        .post(
            '....',
            body,
            options
        )
        .map(res => res.json()).subscribe((result) => {
            if (result) {
                ....
            }
        });
```

UPD:

I've tried @Akshay Khale method and It still doesn't work. I still get headers with out content type

[image: Headers of request]

RESOLUTION:

The problem was in a back-end side. CORS-configuration had been made in a wrong way. And ASP.NET CORE blocked all custom headers. Thank everyone for help

Comment: Can you try passing raw object instead of stringified one?

Comment: try to send `this.loginModel` directly without `stringify` it

Comment: you won't need to do `JSON.stringify` the request parameters when `content-type` is `application/json`

Comment: I've tried. But it still doesn't work

Comment: you can accept your answer and close the question...

Comment: @AkshayKhale done. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in a back-end side. 
CORS-configuration had been made in a wrong way. And ASP.NET CORE blocked all custom headers.
Thank everyone for helping

P.S.

I wrote a few lines about this problem in my [blog](http://egorikas.com/web/cors-in-aspnet-core/)

Answer (score 2):

In your code first option should work but in the second parameter you won't need to do `JSON.stringify`.

Below is the Code that is working

It will hit the given remote URL with Post request and console dump the returned data.

```
let body:any = { "parameter1": "value1", "parameter2": "value2" };
let url = "example.com";
let response:any;
let headers    = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options    = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.post(url, body, options).map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
                     data => { response = data },
                     err => console.error(err),
                     () => { console.log(response) });
```

happy to help :) :) :)

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using Angular 4 `RequestOptionsArgs` instead of `RequestOptions` as below,

The official documentation for this is in Experiemental status

```
post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable<Response>
```

Modify your code as,

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('authentication', `3123123123`);

let options : RequestOptionsArgs ={ 
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/user/login',
    method: RequestMethod.Post,
    search : '',
    headers : headers,
    withCredentials : 'false',
    responseType : ResponseContentType.Json
    }

this.http
.post('http://localhost:5000/api/user/login', 
             JSON.parse(this.loginModel), options)
             .subscribe((result) => {
                 if (result) {
                     .......
                 }
});
```